# Why the direct product does not form a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Prove the direct product of rings never form a ring.

And be the direct product $A\times B$:

$+$: $(x,y) + (z,t) = (x+z,y+t)$

$*$: $(x,y) * (z,t) = (x*z, y*t)$

$x,z\in A$.

If we define $A$ and $B$ both commutative rings, with units and inverses itself (So $A$ and $B$ are fields).

Now, $A\times B$ is commutative, it is a ring, there is a unity element.

And since $A$ and $B$ have inverses, the inverse of each element in $A\times B$ $(x,y)$ is just $(x^{-1},y^{-1})$, being $x^{-1}$ the inverse of $x$ in $A$, and so to $y$ in $B$.

So
$$(x,y) * (x^{-1},y^{-1}) = (e_{a},e_{b})$$

Defining the unity of $A\times B$ as $(e_{a},e_{b})$

I can't see the error in my writings.

Comment: Note that $(0,1)*(1,0)=(0,0)$. Since they are zero divisors, $(1,0)^{-1}$ and $(0,1)^{-1}$ do not exist.

Comment: Please, use MathJax. You just have to put formulas between dollar symbols (e.g., `$x^{-1}$` becomes $x^{-1}$)

Answer (score 4):

The direct product of *fields* is never a field; because we have zero divisors, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, for instance, it is not even an integral domain.

But the direct product of rings is a ring.

Comment: Ops i wanted to say field instead of rings... Anyway, what is the problem in have zero divisors? The definition i saw of fields is:


Commutative,
Unity, and
nonzero invertible.

If it has no zero divisors, so it is an integral domain.

Is this definition wrong?

Comment: A field is a commutative ring in which all the nonzero elements are units.  A zero divisor is nonzero but can't be a unit.

Comment: @GabrielaDaSilva Zero divisors are never invertible under multiplication. Prove this.

Comment: Except in the zero ring!